# Calendar replies in a cross-forest environment

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

My org is set up in a cross-forest Exchange environment.  Domain A is Exchange 2010 and Domain B Exchange 2013.  We haven't migrated mailboxes yet and for our executive admins that manage execs in both orgs have two mailboxes, one in each domain.  The scenario here is one exec admin has mailbox in Domain A forward all mail to her mailbox in Domain B.  When she sends meeting invites out to a mailbox in Domain A she gets the reply in her Domain A mailbox that then forwards to her Domain B mailbox.  If she sends an invite to a mailbox in Domain B, only her Domain B mailbox gets the reply.  Why is the reply not going to her Domain A mailbox and then forwarding to the Domain B mailbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem.  The Domain B mailbox had the Primary SMTP address of the Domain A mailbox instead of a corresponding mail contact in Domain B for Domain A.  I removed the SMTP address and created a contact in Domain B to point to Domain A and now all traffic goes to that mailbox and then forwards to the mailbox in Domain B.